# ¿Como identificar errores ortográficos en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, procesamiento-de-texto

Alguien conoce algún método para identificar errores ortográficos en textos?,o Conocen alguna librería que pueda facilitar el proceso de identificación.

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/